# PostgreSQL DELETE query hangs (and so does EXPLAIN ANALYZE!)

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to delete a bunch of rows from a table matching a query. The general form of my query is:

`DELETE FROM mytable WHERE _id IN (SELECT _id FROM mytable WHERE ...);`

The `_id` column is a `SERIAL PRIMARY KEY`.

If I run the inner `SELECT` query on its own it runs in about 1 second and returns about 100,000 rows. But when I add the `DELETE` call onto it, it seems to just sit and chug away. And chug away. I let it run for about a minute or so, and then cancelled it assuming no progress was being made.

I added `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` onto the front of it to see if I could check what was taking so long, but that call also hangs for a very long period of time.

Can anybody tell me what could be going on such that it's very quick to identify the rows I'd like to delete but takes an indeterminate amount of time to delete them?

**Update**: The full query is as follows.

```
DELETE FROM cards 
WHERE _id IN (
    SELECT _id
    FROM cards
    LEFT JOIN game_results ON game_results.card_id = cards._id 
    WHERE NOT available
    AND game_id IS NULL
)
```

A simplified version of the tables would be:

```
CREATE TABLE cards (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, available BOOLEAN);
CREATE TABLE games (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE game_results (game_id INTEGER REFERENCES games, card_id INTEGER REFERENCES cards);
```

I'm sure this query would eventually finish running, I'm just surprised at how long it's taking given that retrieving all of the IDs to delete is so quick.

**Solution:**

The problem was three-fold!

1. I had one of the earlier (very slow!) queries running that had been triggered by an aborted script. The query was still running even though the script had been aborted. As such, operations like trying to drop indexes were locked waiting for the query to finish. Manually cancelling that query using `pg_cancel_backend` allowed me to experiment with dropping indexes and foreign key constraints.
2. Foreign key constraints seem to be the issue slowing everything down. The fact that the `game_results` table referenced `cards` made the delete take forever. The funny thing is, I was only deleting cards explicitly *unused* in the game_results, but of course that didn't stop the foreign key checks from happening upon delete! That made things very slow. I dropped the foreign key constraint before running the delete and that sped things up to a level I felt was appropriate.
3. For whatever reason, the *second* delete query in the accepted answer ran much quicker than the first.

By combining these three things I was able to do the whole delete in a few seconds, whereas until I had combined these three factors together my queries were running to 5-10 minutes (before I was cancelling them!).

Thanks to all for the help!

Comment: Is this the actual query? If yes, why not the simpler: `DELETE FROM mytable WHERE ...`? Why the subquery?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ The subquery joins to a separate table to check for conditions. It seemed a bit irrelevant to put the details in there because that inner `SELECT` runs quite quickly. Is it possible that somehow the `DELETE` is re-evaluating the inner `SELECT` for each row? If so, that'd take a very long time.

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual problem is - if there is one. A `DELETE` is different than a `SELECT`. It has to actually write to the disk and mark all those (100k) rows as deleted. And update all indexes in the table. And cascade delete in other tables (if there are FKs with such actions). And call triggers if you have on the table.

Comment: I suggest you post the actual query and the tables' structure (CREATE TABLE) for all involved tables.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Sounds good -- I've updated the question with a more detailed query.

Comment: I don't think you're answering @ypercubeᵀᴹ's first comment.

Comment: @EvanCarroll The full query was posted in the update... So yes, it's the actual query.

Comment: Please don't simplify the tables. We do want to know for example if the columns are nullable or not. And their indexes.

Comment: @aardvarkk I read @ypercubeTM to be asking why you're using a subquery in an `IN()` when you could be doing `DELETE FROM mytable USING` (PostgreSQL-specific syntax that should be faster and safer).

Comment: Do you have any indexes on `game_results`?

Comment: `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` actually executes the query — if you want to see the plan without executing, use `EXPLAIN`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the columns are not nullable, the query can be simplified (without the self join) to using either `NOT IN` or `NOT EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM cards 
WHERE available = FALSE 
  AND _id NOT IN 
      ( SELECT card_id
        FROM game_results 
      ) ;

DELETE FROM cards AS c 
WHERE c.available = FALSE
  AND NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM game_results AS gr
        WHERE gr.card_id = c._id
      ) ;
```

Still, deleting 100K rows can not be instantaneous. Performance may be affected by lack (or excess) of indexes, triggers, cascade deletes, etc.

You can use `EXPLAIN` (only, without `ANALYZE`) to get the execution plan of a `DELETE`. See [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-explain.html) for details, especially if you want to try `ANALYZE` or other options of EXPLAIN:

> Important: **Keep in mind that the statement is actually executed when the `ANALYZE` option is used.** Although `EXPLAIN` will discard any output that a SELECT would return, other side effects of the statement will happen as usual. If you wish to use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on an `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `CREATE TABLE AS`, or `EXECUTE` statement without letting the command affect your data, use this approach:
>
> ```
> BEGIN;
> EXPLAIN ANALYZE ...;
> ROLLBACK;
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to peek into the performance including all of those factors? All of the refactors of the query seem to still take a very long time, so that's telling me that some kind of index or trigger issue may be occupying a lot of time.

Comment: @aardvarkk can you test without the indexes, or clone the table and test the delete on the clone?

Comment: @JackDouglas Yep. I'm actually just trying to drop the indexes right now... and the first one I'm trying to drop is taking forever also! Interesting.

Comment: @aardvarkk DROP INDEX should be quick if it is not blocked. You can check: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: @JackDouglas Yep -- that's definitely a part of what's going on. There was a ruby script running a query that was locked for some reason. By cancelling that process the index dropped almost immediately. I'm sure that was a huge part of my problem!

Comment: @aardvarkk there is a good chance that is what was blocking the delete too then

Comment: It's running well now -- a combination of the stalled query, the foreign key constraint, and not using your first suggested query brought the delete time down to a few seconds. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

Check nothing is [blocking](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring) the `DELETE`:

> Looking at pg_locks shows you what locks are granted and what processes are waiting for locks to be acquired. A good query to start looking for lock problems:
>
> ```
> SELECT relation::regclass, * FROM pg_locks WHERE NOT GRANTED;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't ideal.

```
DELETE FROM cards 
WHERE _id IN (
    SELECT _id
    FROM cards
    LEFT JOIN game_results ON game_results.card_id = cards._id 
    WHERE NOT available
    AND game_id IS NULL
);
```

Instead try [`DELETE ... USING`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html)

```
DELETE FROM cards
USING game_results AS gr
WHERE _id = gr.card_id
  AND NOT gr.available
  AND gr.game_id IS NULL;
```

> Yeah, I was writing a similar comment. I'm trying to find any "cards" that were never used in a game by doing the left join to the game results and then checking for empty rows. – aardvarkk 1 min ago

If that's what you're trying to do go for this using `NOT EXISTS`..

```
DELETE FROM cards
WHERE NOT available
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM game_results
    WHERE game_results.card_id = _id 
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is equivalent rewrite. `USING` is equivalent to `INNER JOIN` of the two tables. The original has `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Yeah, I was writing a similar comment. I'm trying to find any "cards" that were *never used* in a game by doing the left join to the game results and then checking for empty rows. In fact, I think I can avoid using the games table altogether. Let me update.

Comment: So then why do an IN, not a `NOT EXISTS`?

Comment: @EvanCarroll Great question! That could be a possible solution! I haven't used that structure before. I'll look into it and see what I can find.

Comment: @aardvarkk check that out

Comment: The delete still seems to be taking a dog's age. I guess maybe my expectations are off in terms of speed. I assumed that since the finding of the IDs was comparatively quick, the delete would occupy about the same amount of time. But as has been mentioned a `DELETE` has to adjust a bunch of indexes and write to disk, so perhaps that's just taking way longer that I thought it would. I'll leave the call running and see how long it takes!

Comment: In my experience, if `DELETE` is slow, the cause is usually missing `INDEX` on some foreign key reference. Note that `DELETE` needs index in the origin column that references some another column (in the same table or another table).